# HTML input tag without a textbox

Tags: html

I am trying to create a cart feature by creating a form and setting different inputs as the value that would be sent to a servlet in order to be processed. There would be multiple products on the page and <kbd>addtocart</kbd> button next to them. Like the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fH7e9.png) here:

[image]

But my problem is each input tag comes with a text box that would ruin the page. How do I get rid the text boxes.

```html
<form name="electronicsitemscart" action="electronicsitemscart" method="get">

    <input name="kind" value="2021 Apple 11-inch iPad Pro (Wi-Fi, 128GB) - Space Gray">

    <input name="price" value="800">

    <input name="orderbutton" class="cbutton" type="submit" value="Addtocart">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using hidden input types.

```
<input type="hidden" value="800">
```

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob edited my answer. Old habit of mine to remind myself I don't need a closing tag lol. Thanks

Comment: In order to do that, you already need to know it doesn't need a closing tag. Since you already know, you don't need to do that.

Comment: Like I said, it's a habit. I know that I don't need to wet my lips every 5 minutes, but I do it sometimes.